# change wordpress page title before rendering (also in Posts Page, etc)

Tags: wordpress

Is there some kind of code I can use to edit the post title before it renders?

It's to do with translation.

For example, I have a post title such as "ITALIAN - RED" and I'd like to change it to "ITALIANO - ROSSO" when it appears on the page.  (What I'm after is actually a lot more complicated than this but this is the idea behind it all.)

If it's possible, I'd like to do this on individual posts as well as pages like POSTS-PAGES which lists all recent posts, widgets which list latest posts and search results.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To change the specific post title use the filter hook `the_title`.

See the below code :

```
function change_title( $title ) {
  if ( $title == 'ITALIAN - RED' ) {
    // Do something with the title
     return 'ITALIANO - ROSSO';
  }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_title' );
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Awesome. Thanks!